# Opening form for second time throws runtime error 9 Excel VBA

Tags: forms, vba, excel

So I have a form which generates a new workbook, saves it and then returns the user to a control form using this little snipped below (note - this doesn't include all the data manipulation):

```
    'create new workbook
        Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        With NewWorkbook
        On Error GoTo Finish
            .Title = "Project Milestones" & projectref
            .SaveAs Filename:=savelocation & "\" & projectref & " Project_Order.xlsx"
        End With

        ' ===== Fixed the error on thie line =====
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Sheets("Project Order Template").Copy Before:=Workbooks(projectref & " Project_Order.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")

        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E6:E7").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E9:E10").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E15:E16").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E6:E7").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E21:E22").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E27:k35").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E40:E43").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E48:E50").ClearContents
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        MsgBox ("Project Order data compiled.")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Unload Me
        frm_Control.Show
        Exit Sub
        End
    End If




Finish:

        Workbooks(projectref & " Project_Order.xlsx").Saved = True
        Workbooks(projectref & " Project_Order.xlsx").Close
        Kill (savelocation & "\" & projectref & " Project_Order.xlsx")
        Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
        With NewWorkbook
            .Title = "Project Milestones" & projectref
            .SaveAs Filename:=savelocation & "\" & projectref & " Project_Order.xlsx"
        End With


        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Project Order Template").Copy Before:=NewWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E6:E7").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E9:E10").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E15:E16").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E6:E7").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E21:E22").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E27:k35").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E40:E43").ClearContents
        Workbooks("COFFIE Project Tracker V2.0.0").Worksheets("Project Order template").Range("E48:E50").ClearContents
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        MsgBox ("Project Order data compiled.")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

However, the user may want to run further reports from the "Report control" form, so they would then click the command button on the Main Control form, and it would take them to the report control form. However, when the  `cmd_reprot_Click()` runs for the second time, it throws a runtime error 9 - subscript out of range. I though I could "get around" this problem by having an error handler try and force the form to open, but it still trows the same error. (see code below for button)

```
Private Sub cmd_reprot_Click()
On Error GoTo display
frm_Control.Hide
frm_reportControl.Show 'error throws here and goes to error handler below

display:
    frm_reportControl.Show ' still throws the runtime 9 error
End Sub
```

My Question is - Why would I be getting a runtime error 9 on the second attempt at opening a form, and what, if any, workaround is there?

**EDIT: here is the button event updated as per BruceWayne's suggestion in the comments**

```
Private Sub cmd_reprot_Click()
On Error GoTo display
If frm_Control.Visible = True Then
    frm_Control.Hide
    frm_reportControl.Show
Else
    frm_reportControl.Show
End If
display:
    If frm_Control.Visible = True Then
        frm_Control.Hide
        frm_reportControl.Show
    Else
        frm_reportControl.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Happy to provide more information if required!

Comment: When they click `cmd_reprot_Click` (note there's a typo) a second time, is the `frm_Control` already hidden? Also, take out the error handler, does that help narrow it down, or show a different error?  After you run that main code (first you posted), you say "...and then returns the user to a control form...". So, it's visible already, yes? And then when they click the button that launches `cmd_reprot_Click`, it hides it...?

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yeah fully aware of the typo (its a consistent typo so theres no 'problem' there XD. The `cmd_report_Click` is located on `frm_Control` which gets hidden, so It gets: Hidden, shown, then hidden again. Taking out the error handler throws the same error, just at the first .show line

Comment: When it throws the error, I assume the `frm_Control` is already hidden? Perhaps you need to add something like `If frm_Control.Visible = True Then // frm_Control.Hide`?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes the Control form is hidden, but the error still gets thrown at the `frm_reportControl.Show ` line, even with the check suggested.

Comment: If the  form is hidden, and you check what @BruceWayne suggested, then it should skip that line. right?

Comment: @BruceWayne - is the edit above how you intended the button event was meant to be checked?

Comment: I seriously doubt that's what he meant. He'll respond by himself of course.

Comment: @BruceWayne I have fixed the problem and posted the answer below. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the problem, it turns out I was Unloading the report form once the report had been generated. Then, if the user wanted to try and re-open the form, there was nothing to `.Show` because it had been unloaded.

To fix the problem, I simply replaced the `Unload Me` line with `frm_reportControl.Hide`. Haven't seen that pesky error 9 again!